# How do I import judo.js?

Tags: node.js, module

Disclaimer: I am new to node.js.

According to this documentation: https://www.npmjs.com/package/judo I should be able to use judo like `var judo = new Judo(options)`

When I try to do that, `Judo` is undefined. How do I import the module?

I've tried `require('judo')` but that didn't do anything.

Answer (score 1):

You should specify the variable name for `require` like this:

```
var Judo = require('judo');
var judo = new Judo(options);
```